# jQuery AJAX: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update my `div` content with new content when the user uses the search `textbox`:

```
$('#business_request_filter_search_textbox').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/housekeeping/business/" + $("#search_filter_selection")[0].selectedIndex == 1 ? "get-requests-by-username" : "get-requests-by-business-name";
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: { search: $('input#business_request_filter_search_textbox').val() },
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            $('#request_area').html('<center>Please wait while we gather results...</center>');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#request_area').html(data);
        },
    });
});
```

Now I have a dropdown selecting what they want to filter the search by, the username or the business name. This is the line that is throwing the error.

```
url: "/ajax/housekeeping/business/" + $("#search_filter_selection")[0].selectedIndex == 1 ? "get-requests-by-username" : "get-requests-by-business-name";
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you check this `$("#search_filter_selection")[0].selectedIndex == 1 ? "get-requests-by-username" : "get-requests-by-business-name"` condition ?

Comment: may be try ($("#search_filter_selection")[0].selectedIndex == 1) ? "get-requests-by-username" : "get-requests-by-business-name" with brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a comma ',' at the end of the `url` line:

```
$('#business_request_filter_search_textbox').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/housekeeping/business/" + $("#search_filter_selection")[0].selectedIndex == 1 ? "get-requests-by-username" : "get-requests-by-business-name",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: { search: $('input#business_request_filter_search_textbox').val() },
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            $('#request_area').html('<center>Please wait while we gather results...</center>');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#request_area').html(data);
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have dataType defined for the ajax call.
Add dataType which is the expected format of your ajax request which can be text, json etc

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
$('#business_request_filter_search_textbox').on('input propertychange paste', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/housekeeping/business/" + $("#search_filter_selection")[0].selectedIndex == 1 ? "get-requests-by-username" : "get-requests-by-business-name",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: { search: $('input#business_request_filter_search_textbox').val() },
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            $('#request_area').html('<center>Please wait while we gather results...</center>');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#request_area').html(data);
        },
    });
});
```

Hope This help You :) Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
data: { search: $('input#business_request_filter_search_textbox').val() }
```

to:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ search: $('input#business_request_filter_search_textbox').val() })
```